# Yesterday Node Express API works locally, today getting ENOTFOUND localhost

Tags: express, npm

I have been working on several Node Express APIs and while they were working yesterday, I have rebooted my machines (laptop and workstation) and they are giving ENOTFOUND error for localhost (syscall getaddress info). I have thoroughly tested these APIs and I'm still getting:

```
  error:  Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND locahost
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
    errno: -3008,
    code: 'ENOTFOUND',
    syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
    hostname: 'locahost',
    fatal: true
  }
```

I am using Ubuntu (WSL) on both machines. I've checked /etc/hosts and 127.0.0.1 is localhost. I am lost as to what to do from here. I'm ready to test a third API and it's giving the same error. I deleted `rm -rf` node_modules and reinstalled. Still no go.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `locahost` is what shows in the error message and it looks like a mispelling.  Shouldn't it be `localhost`?

Comment: localhost:3000/ renders -> {
    "message": "Welcome to the VirtualYou Financial API Express application."
} and ... localhost:3000/api-docs renders Swagger Docs

Comment: Your error message shows `locahost`.

Comment: I'm grepping now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm if there is a localhost connection issue you will try also like instead of

```
'127.0.0.1'
```

replace this IP with your localhost string and write into string :)

**FYI** **check your port also, it will run on a particular port** :)